# How do I use jQuery to insert a second background into an inline style based on a class?

Tags: jquery, css, background-image, linear-gradients

I searched for this issue but could not find it, any help would be appreciated.

I have a header div that has a background image called dynamically, so the background image is called inline using the style attribute. I need to have a second background on top of it, a top layer that's a css gradient, so I need to use CSS multiple backgrounds. But I have two choices for the gradient color, a black gradient or a white gradient, depending on whether the photo is predominantly light or dark. So when an admin is setting up a page they upload the photo and then decide if it needs a light or dark gradient on top. This is done by an ACF field. They decide this and the code has a class added to it, 'light' or 'dark'.

Here's my code:

```
<section id="header-block" style="background-image: url(<?php echo $feat_image[0]; ?>);" class="<?php if( get_field('header_theme') == 'dark' ): ?>dark<?php elseif( get_field('header_theme') == 'light' ): ?>light<?php endif; ?>">
```

So I need is a second linear-gradient background to be inserted as a string before 'url' in the style attribute based on whether the class is 'light' or 'dark'.

So insert:

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,.95) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%),
```

if the class is 'dark' or:

```
linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%),
```

if the class is 'light'.

The result (one example) would be:

```
<section id="header-block" style="background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,.95) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%), url('/path/to/image.jpg');" class="dark">
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the pseudo as Michael Coker stated, but to accomplish this using jQuery you would use:

```js
$(".dark, .light").each(function() {
 $this = $(this);
  back = $this.css("backgroundImage");
  
  if ( $this.hasClass('dark') ) {
   lin = "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,.95) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%), "
  } else if ( $this.hasClass('light') ) {
   lin = "linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%), ";
  }
  
  $this.css("backgroundImage",  lin + back)
  
})
```

```css
.light-bk {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,.95) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%);
  }

.dark-bk {
   background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<section style="background-image: url('/path/to/image.jpg');" class="js-addBG dark">
```

(Inspect the code to see the results)

[JSfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Chris_Happy/Ld9n9mha/)

Answer (score 1):

I would use a pseudo element on that block to make the overlay.

```css
#header-block {
  position: relative;
  /* you don't need this height/width, just for my demo */  
  width: 560px; height: 400px;
}

#header-block:after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0; left: 0; right: 0; bottom: 0;
}

#header-block.light:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(255,255,255,.95) 0%, rgba(255,255,255,.6) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%);
}

#header-block.dark:after {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0,0,0,.8) 0%, rgba(0,0,0,.4) 50%, rgba(255,255,255,0) 70%);
}
```

```html
<section id="header-block" style="background-image: url(http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png);" class="dark">
</section>

<section id="header-block" style="background-image: url(http://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/img/fonz1.png);" class="light">
</section>
```

Comment: Ahhh interesting idea! I'm going to try it.

Comment: I decided to go with the jQuery version below, but thank you I learned something from you!

Comment: @AlisonCohn you're welcome. I'm curious why? CSS is far more performant than using jQuery.

Comment: good point. I saw benefits in doing it both ways and for some reason I had my mind set on jQuery. I'm going to reevaluate.

Comment: @AlisonCohn in general CSS > javascript > jquery. CSS happens basically automatically in the browser, no logic or unnecessary code or anything. Javascript is better, but in the case of the answer you chose, it's looping through the code and just applying CSS. The browser already goes through the code, so it's redundant for Javascript to go through it, too. Then they are writing javascript to apply CSS... when you could just use CSS. jQuery is even more inefficient. It requires the entire jQuery library, and jQuery will run Javascript, then the JS will apply CSS. I'd just write CSS :)